# baguettebox on event won't load config params

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, baguettebox

I'm using vuejs and moved this code from methods to an on event.
Now it doesn't load the background config but shows transparent and default. Why?

```
... // vue.comp
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      // window.baguetteBox.show(0, gallery[0]);
      this.$root.$on('startCarousel', i => {
        let gallery = window.baguetteBox.run('.gallery', {
          overlayBackgroundColor: 'hsl(171, 100%, 41%)'
        });

        window.baguetteBox.show(i, gallery[0]);
      });
    },


// another comp html 
                <figure class="image">
                  <img :src="exe.img" :alt="exe.name" @click="$root.$emit('startCarousel', index)">
                </figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `this.$root.$on` and `this.$root.$emit` are not necessary and confusing.

If the `<figure>` is in another comp, just do `$emit('start-carousel', index)` directly, and in the parent:

```
<my-comp-width-figure @start-carousel="handleEvent" />
```

If the `<figure>` is **directly** in the comp, then no need to do emits or whatsoever since both the handler and emitter are in the same context, just do:

```
<figure class="image">
  <img :src="exe.img" :alt="exe.name" @click="handleEvent(index)">
</figure>
```

In both situations, `handleEvent` would be the code that you have in your `this.$root.$on`.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: they are like brother components, not parent-child. It wouldn't work without the $root

Comment: If they are brother component, then the whole approach is wrong. Events are meant for that kind of use case.

Comment: My best guess would be to check what contains "gallery" to be sure the event are sent correctly. In any case, using the root instance to share data is not recommended at all. Either use a specifc event bus or a global state for this kind of use-case.